# str not tuple error when running pandas code

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm creating a memory quiz game where it asks the user about their day (using python).

I'm trying to create a progress graph using matplotlib and pandas, however, when I run the code, I get the following error:

> pandas.errors.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql '('SELECT Date, Score FROM scoring WHERE UserID =?', ('Kgarda43',))': execute() argument 1 must be str, not tuple

This is my code for the area I am getting an error:

```
connection=sqlite3.connect('Memory.db')
cursor=connection.cursor()
sql=("SELECT Date, Score FROM scoring WHERE UserID =?", (Username_Login.value,))
data= pandas.read_sql(sql,connection)#collecting the data
```

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the UserID field in your database is supposed to be a string, therefore upon finding this error:

```
execute() argument 1 must be str, not tuple
```

You can fix it by correctly using your commas inside your query:

```
sql= '''
SELECT Date, Score 
FROM scoring 
WHERE UserID ='?'
     '''
```

Comment: I seem to be getting the same error :\

Comment: I have edited my comment. Forgot to remove brackets, therefore the query was still technically a tuple.